# Outlook 2013 background image renders differently on different computers

Tags: html, image, background, outlook

I put a large, animated background gif into an HTML table.  I used a standard Outlook trick so that the background will show up.  I don't expect it to animate, but at least show the first frame.  On top of the image, I have different URLs and html text for a promo code.  So, I used transparent spacer images to set the spacing so I could link the different sections.

This code works fine on all platforms and browsers, including Outlook 2013. However, on some computers, the background image seems to blow up, or be zoomed in, and so the email looks distorted.  We checked that all our outlook and computer display settings are the same.

Why do this email appear differently on different computers, even though it works perfect on others?

---

```
<table width="684" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="center" width="684" height="762" background="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/sfly/y/2016/P21626_summer_animate_v2.gif" style="background-color:#ffffff; min-width:684px;">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:684px;height:762px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/sfly/y/2016/P21626_summer_animate_v2.gif" color="##ffffff" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
    <div>
    <table width="684" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="684" height="29" colspan="2"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="684" height="29" border="0" alt="48 HOURS ONLY"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="342" height="243"><a href="#"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="342" height="243" border="0" alt="ONE NOTEPAD"></a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="342" height="243"><a href="#"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="342" height="243" border="0" alt="ONE MAGNET"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="684" height="206" colspan="2"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="684" height="206" border="0" alt="CHOOSE TWO FREE GIFTS"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="684" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="248" height="66"><a href="#"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="248" height="66" border="0" alt="ONE 8x10 ART PRINT"></a></td>
        <td valign="top" align="center" width="190" height="66" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #000001; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; min-width:190px;"><span class="apple_link" style="color:#000001; text-decoration: none;">Offer ends Sunday<br>Code: 2DELIGHTS</span></td>
        <td valign="top" width="246" height="66"><a href="#"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="246" height="66" border="0" alt="ONE PLACEMAT"></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="684" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="342" height="218"><a href="#"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="342" height="218" border="0" alt="ONE 8x10 ART PRINT"></a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="342" height="218"><a href="#"><img style="display: block;" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/e/z/spacer_60x80.gif" width="342" height="218" border="0" alt="ONE PLACEMAT"></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
    </v:rect>
<![endif]-->

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: here's a screenshot of the issue.  The background image appears larger than the table it's contained in.  Works on some PC Outlook 2013 computers, but not others.  I assume it's some obscure setting difference between computers, but can't figure out what.   https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/sfly/y/2016/P21626_screenshot1.jpg

Comment: I found on another post that this will fix the issue of inconsistent rendering on Outlook 2013 on different computers.  Use <v:fill type="frame"

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I thought I'd make Chris's comment an official answer since it worked for me.

In the `<v:fill>` element change the `type` attribute to `frame`.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:684px;height:762px;">
        <v:fill type="frame" src="https://cdn.staticsfly.com/i/sfly/y/2016/P21626_summer_animate_v2.gif" color="##ffffff" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
```